# How to assign values entered in a textbox to a combobox selection on another form MS Access using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with 6 textboxes, 3 of which hold the updated monetary value of monthly, quarterly and annual membership types. In another form I have a combobox with the 3 types of membership, when a membership type is selected I want to output the updated monetary value of the selection to a textbox. Would appreciate if anyone could help/recommend any resourceful links. My vba understanding is decent however struggling with writing code that runs correctly.

```
Private Sub cbMmemberType_change()

 If cbMemberType.Text = "Monthly" Then
        frmSubscriptionDetails.txtSubCost.Text = frmUpdatedCosts.txtUpdatedMonth.Text
    ElseIf cbMemberType.Text = "3 Months" Then
         frmSubscriptionDetails.txtSubCost.Text = frmUpdatedCosts.txtUpdated3Months.Text
    ElseIf cbMemberType.Text = "Annual" Then
         frmSubscriptionDetails.txtSubCost.Text = frmUpdatedCosts.txtUpdatedAnnual.Text

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The *Text* property is only valid when the control has focus, and use the *AfterUpdate* event, so try:

```vb
Private Sub cbMmemberType_AfterUpdate()

    Select Case Me!cbMemberType.Value
        Case "Monthly" 
            frmSubscriptionDetails!txtSubCost.Value = frmUpdatedCosts!txtUpdatedMonth.Value
        Case "3 Months" 
            frmSubscriptionDetails!txtSubCost.Value = frmUpdatedCosts!txtUpdated3Months.Value
        Case "Annual" Then
            frmSubscriptionDetails!txtSubCost.Value = frmUpdatedCosts!txtUpdatedAnnual.Value
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort and reply, unfortunately this code just breaks the project, based on which member type i select it highlights the line after the case, unsure why